# Data Structure for Mapping IP to City

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures

I was reading interview questions from different companies and I came across this one:

```
You are given a fixed file. The format of each line is city name, ip address
range. Construct a data structure and design algorithm to achieve efficient
mapping from an ip address to city name.
```

One way I think would work, albeit in linear time is with a simple  Linked List, where you have the starting IP for the given range and inside the node you have the city and the final IP in the range.

Thus when looking for something, you iterate through the list and check the start and end ip addresses to see if the given IP is within any of the ranges.

This assumes that the IP ranges don't overlap.

Does someone have a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store an IP address on 32 bits, so just convert them to ints then store the `(IP, City)` pairs in any [balanced BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) or [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) where the key is the IP. Look-up complexity will be logarithmic or constant this way.

Comment: For integer keys, there are more efficient maps for integer keys than the comparison-based BSTs, such as tries and van Emde Boas trees.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a tree structure for each of the dotted sections and leaf nodes would be cities

```
Root
|
[0-13]     [14-255]
|              |
[0-255]    [0-173],    [174-255]
|              |                |
[0-255]    [0-255]      [0-255]
|              |                |
[0-255]    [0-255]      [0-255]
|              |                |
London   Belfast      Berlin
```

Etc. then the map an address to a city you'd just walk the tree so 14.183.1.123 would be Berlin